# Partition Mounting Problem

Tags: mount

I have a NTFS partition called DATA which automatically mount at boot (on /media/DATA). It gone good since now: in /media I have a DATA empty folder which i can't delete, and a DATA_ folder, where the DATA partition is mounted. How can I remount my partition on /media/DATA and not on /media/DATA_ anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like previously created `DATA` folder existed when you boot up your machine so the system created a new one. I think you can delete the old one and after reboot - it should be mounted as `DATA` again.

`sudo rmdir /media/DATA`

reboot

if it works then I would expect `DATA_` empty this time, so lastly you can delete it too:

`sudo rmdir /media/DATA_`

Comment: IMHO `rmdir` would be preferable to `rm -r` since it avoids the possibility of accidentally removing the contents of the mounted filesystem.

Comment: @steeldriver nice comment, I've fixed it in the answer.